# Why can't I see my console.log output in the Azure Monitoring Logs from my node.js (hapi) web app in Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, hapi

I'm seeing the console.log output appearing in the Azure log stream which is fine for investigating issues that I can recreate, but if I want to go back to something that happened before I had opened up the log stream I'm assuming that the Azure Monitoring Logs tool is the place to go?

I may be using the wrong query but I'm starting with their example which is:

```
AppServiceConsoleLogs
```

I've also tried registering pino as below, but my code is not calling any specific pino functions, so I don't think this is doing anything.

```
module.exports = {
  plugin: require('hapi-pino'),
  options: {
    redact: ['req.headers.authorization'],
    logPayload: true,
    level: config.isDev ? 'debug' : 'warn'
  }
}
```

I'm seeing nothing in these logs at all, let alone any of my console.log output.

I've also tried setting up Application Insights, which does seem to output some detail but I can't see the console.log output anywhere still.